# Her love letters--to and from Daddy--were in an old box,

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, capitalization

Her love letters--to and from Daddy--were in an old box, tied with ribbons and stiff, rigid-with-age leather thongs:1918 through 1920;...
Why (Daddy) in this sentence was written with a capital D?

Comment: Why not, *Girl*? :) -- (Yes, I know many style guides might say not to do that.)

Comment: I don't know why

Comment: "Daddy" is the 'name', 'appellation' she used to address her dad. The president is usually addressed thus: "Mr President". The capitalisation is to honour / show respect / acknowledge status.

Comment: Many so-called grammar sources might say that it ought to be "daddy", but when you read a lot of fiction, you'll sometimes see it written as "Daddy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that if you can replace the name *Daddy/Mommy/Dad/Mom* with a name, then it gets capitalized.

> I received 20 letters from (**Daddy.**)
> I received 20 letters from (**John.**)

That works, so capitalize Daddy.

> I received 20 letters from my (**Daddy.**)
> I received 20 letters from my (**John**). Wrong. Using **my dad** means no capital, because one should not say *my* John normally.

[Guide:](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g71.html) capitalize words such as "Mother," "Father," "Grandmother," "Grandfather," "Son," "Daughter," and "Sis" when they are used in place of the person's name. Do not capitalize them when they follow possessive pronouns such as her, his, my, our, your.

> **Mother** wrote to **Father** every day. **Mary** wrote to **John** every day. - **correct**
>
> **My Mother** wrote to **Father** every day. **My Mary** wrote to **John** every day. - **incorrect.**  **My Mary** is not used this way.
> **My mother** wrote to **Father** every day. - **correct**

Comment: Why My Mary is incorrect?

Comment: Er, then how about *"Today, I received a letter from Daughter"*? -- Also, *"My mother wrote to Father every day"* is a bit weird looking. Perhaps more consistent would be *"Mother wrote to Father every day"*.

Comment: How about "my son calls me dad/Dad."? Should Dad be capitalized in this sentence?

Comment: Son calls me Dad? right?

Comment: @F.E. - That's how I was tught. I personally never called my sisters or brothers "Sis," but some people do. Ergo: *My dad* and *Sis* went fishing, while *Mom*, *Gran,* *Pops,* my brother and I stayed home playing video games. I didn't make them up. See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/when-should-mom-and-dad-be-capitalized).

Comment: @IceGirl and Peter: yes, you are both correct.

Comment: Er, *"My mother wrote to Father every day. And then my father began to suspect she was having an affair with our pastor. And soon, the letter writing stopped. And the texting began."*

Comment: @F.E. - lol Exactly! Which is why it was a big mistake for Daddy to have bought Mom that iPhone to begin with, knowing Pastor Jim.