# Capitalization of "sister" and "brother"

Tags: capitalization, kinship-terms

I have seen the question on [when to capitalize *mom* and *dad*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/when-should-mom-and-dad-be-capitalized), but I am confused why the rule would not apply equally to *Brother* vs. *brother* and *Sister* vs. *sister*.

I.e., if the rule is to use capitals when speaking of a specific mom, as in "my Mom", then should the rule compel me to refer to siblings as "my Sister" and "my Brother"?

It looks perfectly acceptable to capitalize parents, but capitalizing siblings looks extremely odd.

Comment: In contexts like *"You'll have to ask Mum"* (as opposed to *"**your** Mum"*) it seems quite natural to capitalise what is in effect a proper noun usage. The reason this would usually look weird with *brother* or *sister* is partly because often there are *other* siblings of the implied sex, so it can't really be an unambiguous proper noun. Also see [Yes uncle,Yes Uncle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Yes+uncle%2CYes+Uncle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CYes%20uncle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CYes%20Uncle%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - mother/mum, dad, sis, bro are capitalized if standing in for a proper noun, e.g. Sara, Sam, Sally, Steve. Not when used with *my*. However, these are only the *grammar rules*, and I don't object to how people want to do it personally. But as an EL&U forum, we should at least be aware of the convention.

Comment: @medica: I *thought* that was effectively the point I was making. Not that I would ever expect to see [*“Wassup, bro?”*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wassup+bro%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) capitalised, but there are certainly "exotic" contexts like [*Mother curtly asked Brother why the girl was in the hospital, but Brother wanted to hear her opinion about her before he'd answer*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+brother+wanted+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) where (the *orthography*, at least) is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 9):

*Mom* and *Dad* are capitalized when they're used in place of names, e.g. *Hi, Mom* at the beginning of a letter or email.

*Sister* and *brother* are not usually used in this way. If you were to refer to a sibling using the relationship, it's more common to use diminutives *Sis* and *Bro*. If you write *Hi, Sis*, you should capitalize it for the same reason as *Mom* above.

You don't capitalize them when you're using them as ordinary nouns. So you would write *"My mom was home and she made dinner for my sister".*

Comment: That's what I said `My mom` isn't using it as a proper noun, it's just an ordinary noun, that's why I didn't capitalize it.

Answer (score 3):

Sister and Brother are capitalized in the same way as Doctor -- when used as honorifics or titles.  These particular titles, along with "Mother" and "Father", are commonly used by religious orders.

You wouldn't capitalize them (or "mom" or "dad") when used with an article or possessive pronoun.  "my sister" and "my brother" are correct, as are "my mom" and "my dad".

Comment: This is correct when they're being used as honorifics, as you say, but I think @Barmar's answer is closer to what the original question was trying to resolve.