# Why father’s first letter is capital

Tags: orthography

> After they had their supper, Father went into the living-room to watch TV.

Why use Father not father?

Comment: Because it's the "nickname" the narrator uses for his father, and hence a "proper noun".

Comment: This is actually quite an interesting question. Using _Father_ as a proper noun like this is somewhat old-fashioned (or very posh), which is perhaps why it’s capitalised. Much more common alternatives like _dad(dy)_, _pa_, _papa_, _pops_, etc., would be almost never be capitalised, but an uncapitalised _father_ in this context would seem unusual.

Comment: Searching for this sentence only brings up multiple pages with the same Chinese translation exercise. In **none** of those pages is "Father" capitalised. So the capitalisation could be an error in one transcription.

Answer (score 1):

"Father", in this case, is being used as a proper noun. For this reason, it being capitalized is correct.

If the author had written "my father" or "the father", "father" would not be capitalized as it wouldn't be a proper noun in those cases, it would be a common noun.

Comment: Oops, @Laurel is right; this question is basically a duplicate of [When should “Mom” and “Dad” be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/when-should-mom-and-dad-be-capitalized)